# Правильное разбивание

Tags: php

Необходим совет как облагородить код. Есть такой блок занесенный в переменную:

```
<div class="mainTechnicalData">
    <p><strong>Малолитражный автомобиль, Подержанный</strong></p>
    <br>
    <p>П.р. 10/1996</p>
    <p>197 824 км</p>
    <p>Бензиновый</p>
    <p>44 кВт (60 PS)</p>
    <p>Механическая коробка передач</p>
</div>
```

Нужно вытащить и обработать информацию только после br.

Мой план действий:

1) split с указателем '<br>' получаем:

```
        <p>П.р. 10/1996</p>
        <p>197 824 км</p>
        <p>Бензиновый</p>
        <p>44 кВт (60 PS)</p>
        <p>Механическая коробка передач</p>
    </div>
```

Дальше explode с указателем "</p><p>". Получаем 5 значений массива:

```
    <p>П.р. 10/1996
    197 824 км
    Бензиновый
    44 кВт (60 PS)
    Механическая коробка передач
```

Дальше удаляем <p>.

Мой вариант работает, но он мягко говоря индуский. Как можно сделать все проще и красивее?

Comment: думайте в сторону регулярки )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `split()` используйте `explode()`. `split()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0.

Ваш способ, мягко говоря, должен быть самым быстрым. Как вариант:

```
preg_match_all('#<p>(.*?)</p>#u', $text, $array);
array_shift($array[1]);
var_dump($array[1]);
```

иль я вот так придумал:

```
array_slice(
    str_replace(
        array('</p>', '</div>', "\r\n"),
        '',
        explode('<p>', $text)
    ), 
2);
```

Только ко второму способу нужно обязательно оставить комментарий.